# Setting Panels category for blocks and other pre-existing Content Types?

Tags: 7, blocks, panels, chaos-tool-suite

When one adds new content to a Panel, they are given a list of categories, each with various Content Types.

Setting the aforementioned category of a Content Type is easy if you're writing your own plugin...

```
$plugin = array(
  'title' => t('My Plugin'),
  'category' => t('YOUR CATEGORY HERE'),
);
```

But what about setting that category for Content Types created by other modules?

I ask because I've created a [Menu Block](http://drupal.org/project/menu_block) and am wanting to put it in a specific category, where all my other custom CTools Panels Content Type plugins reside.

Any thoughts? I'm using D7, by the way. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A kinda hacky way of doing it is to hook into hook_ctools_block_info() like so:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_ctools_block_info().
 *
 * @see ctools_block_content_type_content_types().
 */
function menu_block_ctools_block_info($module, $delta, &$info) {
  if ($info['title'] == 'Sub Menu Menu Block') {
      $info['icon'] = 'icon_core_block_menu.png';
      $info['category'] = t('Page Content');
  }
}
```

I just dropped this code in a separate module and I'm off to the races. The only problem is if Menu Block decides to implement its own hook_ctools_block_info function (Indeed, I got the above code from [a patch that does exactly that](http://drupal.org/node/1420180)), in which case redeclaration errors will show up. I'll leave this question marked as unanswered for the moment; if anyone can think of a better way of accomplishing the above, I'd be happy to accept that answer instead.